# Iam getting an MYSQL 1064 Error - Can someone help me fix it please

Tags: mysql

iam trying to perform this query in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE forum_asb_sideboxes(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    display_order INT(10) NOT NULL,
    box_type VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    title TEXT,
    title_link VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    POSITION INT(2),
    scripts TEXT,
    groups TEXT,
    themes TEXT,
    settings TEXT,
    wrap_content INT(1),
    dateline INT(10)
) ENGINE = myisam CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Iam getting this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups TEXT,themes TEXT,settings TEXT,wrap_content INT(1),dateline INT(10)) ENGI' at line 1

The thing is this is a mybb plugin that iam trying to install
this plugin works on alot of other mybb based forums
i dont really know what is happening maybe the query is only available for another mysql version

can you tell me how to fix it please

Comment: I tested, it was fine for me!

Comment: `GROUPS` is a reserved word starting in MySQL 8.0.2.

Comment: `groups` is [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G) as of v8.0.2. You can still use the name, but it needs to surround with back-ticks everywhere that it is used.

Comment: If `dateline` is a datetime you should also change the datetype there.